# grouping nodes in drupal with taxonomy

Tags: drupal, list, taxonomy

I have a problem that i cant seem to get my head around.

What i need to do is to create lists in drupal, where you can group nodes together depending on what category they belong to, and also have that category as a header.

ex:

```
- January (category, header)
-- week 1 (category, header)
--- 1. bananas (node)
--- 2. apples (node)
--- 3. pears

-- week 2
--- 1. apples
--- 2. bananas
--- 3. pears
```

or if no week has been set as category:

```
- january
--- 1. bananas
--- 2. apples
--- 3. pears
--- 4. plums
and so on...
```

i've fiddled around with taxonomy in views and i just can't seem to get it right. I'm in a bit of a panic about it right now, so if anyone has got any ideas at all please post it.

Thank you.

/Anders

Answer (score 1):

You can get pretty close to that using month (January) as an argument, and grouping by another vocabulary for the week.

Click on the gear icon in the Views interface next to the Style Plugin. Set `Group By` to your Taxonomy Field.

Also, to remove the "weeks" from the individual entries, go to the Taxonomy entry under Fields, and configure it to `Exclude from Display`.